# User Registration - Display User Uploading Image

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using this plugin for my Wordpress site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/

To display for example, the users country they choose - this is the simple code you can use:-

```
<?php global $current_user; echo $current_user->user_registration_country; ?>
```

This displays the users country they selected on registration. I now want to display their photo they uploaded, so I am doing the following:-

```
<?php global $current_user; echo $current_user->user_registration_upload_picture; ?>
```

However this is only showing the ID of the image within the frontend of the site.

Could someone please help, in how I can convert the ID to display the image url?

Thank you!

Comment: Try if [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) does the trick. Always start by doing some proper research before asking. This link was the first hit when searching for something like "wordpress get image by id".

Answer (score 1):

The ID you're getting is probably the ID of an attachment. You can find the image information using `wp_get_attachment_image_src`, then display it:

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $current_user->user_registration_upload_picture );
if ($image_attributes) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you @alexander!